# Multiple sockets - one of which causing SSLException - how to debug trace openSocket in jsse.jar

Tags: java, debugging, trace, jsse

I've got an issue in an enterprise application that is opening multiple sockets in a particular scenario. I want to trace back from the openSocket method in the SSLSocketFactory in jsse.jar - but the underlying SSL internals classes don't have source code available.

(I'm aware there is another question asking for the source to jsse.jar which doesn't give a conclusive answer - I'm not asking for that.)

My question is - how do you do a debug trace when you don't have access to the source code? (Surely not a JAD based approach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you mean by 'trace back', but JSSE provides the system property -Djavax.net.debug=ssl, which shows everything that JSSE is doing.

Comment: I mean in an ide - put a debug trace marker on the line of source to see when it is being called - to see what is calling it. To "trace back" the openSocket to see what is calling it.